# checkbox property check value not updating in knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, knockout.js

I am working with Knockout.js. I have a page where I have three checkbox and its under `foreach` loop. Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="ko-bind-element">
    <input type="hidden" id="serverJSON" value="@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)" />
    <div data-bind="foreach: procedures">
        <div data-bind="template: { name: Mode(), data: $data }"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="procedure">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-3"><span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { name: (VId.length > 0) ? VId : Name },checked: AlreadyCompleted" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { name: (VId.length > 0) ? VId : Name },checked: NotApplicable" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { name: (VId.length > 0) ? VId : Name },checked: CreateNew" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="padding:0;">
                <div data-bind="if: CreateNew">
                    <textarea style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;" class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-8" data-bind=" value : Text"></textarea>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>
```

As there are three checkbox per row and I wanted only one of them should be selected so I have this jQuery function which selects one checkbox at time per row

```
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
    debugger;
    // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) {
        // the name of the box is retrieved using the .attr() method
        // as it is assumed and expected to be immutable
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
        // the checked state of the group/box on the other hand will change
        // and the current value is retrieved using .prop() method
        $(group).prop("checked", false);
        $box.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $box.prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

But problem is now, When I check 1st checkbox then uncheck it. Then check second checkbox and submit data. Both 1st and 2nd show checked. So don't know whether its Knockout issue.

Here is the binding code:

```
viewModel = {
    MtocFormID: 0,
    procedures: ko.observableArray(),
    dateid: null
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = JSON.parse($("#serverJSON").val());
    viewModel.MtocFormID = ko.observable(data.ID);
    // viewModel.dateid = ko.observable(data.ExpiryDate)
    $(data.TemplateProcedure).each(function(index, element) {
        var mappedItem = {
            //    otherSafetyPro: ko.observableArray([]),
            VId: ko.observable(element.VId),
            TemplateID: ko.observable(element.TemplateID),
            ProcedureTemplateID: ko.observable(element.ProcedureTemplateID),
            Name: ko.observable(element.Name),
            AlreadyCompleted: ko.observable(element.AlreadyCompleted),
            NotApplicable: ko.observable(element.NotApplicable),
            CreateNew: ko.observable(element.CreateNew),
            Text: ko.observable(element.Text),
            Mode: ko.observable("procedure")
        }
        viewModel.procedures.push(mappedItem);
    });
    ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("ko-bind-element"));
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("ko-bind-element"));
    form08wizard.submitData(getSubmitData);
});
```

Comment: Changing `checked` property programmatically will not affect underlying properties in the view model. You have to set values to the corresponding observables (`NotApplicable`, `AlreadyCompleted`, and `CreateNew`) instead of changing checkboxes' states.

Comment: How can I set that?

Comment: you want only 1 of the three checkboxes checked at a time? Sound like you want input type radio

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subscribe` feature to identify if a checkbox is checked then modify the other checkbox. And also I prefer to arrange the viewmodel this way.

```
var singleViewModel = function(element){
  var self = this;
  // self.otherSafetyPro = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.VId = ko.observable(element.VId);
  ...
  self.Completed = ko.observable(element.AlreadyCompleted);
  self.NotApplicable = ko.observable(element.NotApplicable);
  self.CreateNew = ko.observable(element.CreateNew);
  self.Completed.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if(newValue) {
      self.NotApplicable(false);
      self.CreateNew(false);
    }
  });
  self.NotApplicable.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if(newValue) {
      self.Completed(false);
      self.CreateNew(false);
    }
  });
  self.CreateNew.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if(newValue) {
      self.NotApplicable(false);
      self.Completed(false);
    }
  });
}
```

And then this is how you assign it

```
$(data.TemplateProcedure).each(function (index, element) {
  viewModel.procedures.push(new singleViewModel(element));
});
```

Another sample:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.optionA = ko.observable(false);
  self.optionA.subscribe(function(newValue){
    if(newValue) {
      self.optionB(false);
      self.optionC(false); 
    }
  });
  self.optionB = ko.observable(false);
  self.optionB.subscribe(function(newValue){
    if(newValue) {
      self.optionA(false);
      self.optionC(false); 
    }
  });
  self.optionC = ko.observable(false);
  self.optionC.subscribe(function(newValue){
    if(newValue) {
      self.optionA(false);
      self.optionB(false); 
    }
  });
}   

$(document).ready(function () {
  var myViewModel = new ViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: optionA" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: optionB" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: optionC" />
</div>
```

Comment: after adding subscribe code , I am getting this error 'Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined'

Comment: @Mahajan344 I did some modifications. My personal preference is to provide a single function which can be used to create a knockout object. Then if we want to use it, we can just use 'new viewModel(element)' and pass the value as an argument. Also this will allow us to move the implementation to a separate js file.