# model and ui out of sync after manipulating DOM with jQuery - knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have the following 3 checkboxes where only one at a time can be selected:

```
<div class="radio-rows-wrapper" style="padding-top: 10px">
   <input type="checkbox" id="noMandateOption" name="mandate-option-selection" data-bind="checked: NoMandate"/></td>
   <label for="no-mandate">No Mandate</label><br>

   <input type="checkbox" id="electronicMandateOption" name="mandate-option-selection" data-bind="checked: ElectronicMandate" /></td>
   <label for="electronic-mandate">Electronic Mandate</label><br>

   <input type="checkbox" id="uploadMandateOption" name="mandate-option-selection" data-bind="checked: UploadMandate" /></td>
   <label for="upload-mandate">Upload Mandate</label>
</div>
```

I also have 3 sections that should show or hide depending on which checkbox is selected:

```
<div data-bind="if: NoMandate"></div
<div data-bind="if: ElectronicMandate"></div
<div data-bind="if: UploadMandate"></div
```

And the following jQuery for updating the checkboxes:

```
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
            $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false)
        });
```

When a checkbox is selected the correct section displays but after selecting another checkbox the section doesn't get hidden which makes me believe that somewhere the UI get's out of sync and that the values are not updated correctly.

Comment: You have an answer to your question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027852/checkbox-property-check-value-not-updating-in-knockout-js.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case that using jQuery to set the value of a checkbox is not triggering the event which causes a Knockout observable's value to update.

If you're using Knockout then you really don't need that jQuery mechanism for de-selecting those other checkboxes. I can think of two other ways to achieve this.

1. The simplest solution would be to use radio buttons. That's the point of radio buttons - to offer a choice where only one may be selected.
2. Add a `.subscribe(function(val) { ... })` method to each of those observables, and use this to set the others to `false`.

This second idea would look something like...

```
var self = this;

self.ElectronicMandate = ko.observable();
self.ElectronicMandate.subscribe(function(val) {
    deselectOthers(val, self.NoMandate, self.UploadMandate);
});

self.NoMandate = ko.observable();
self.NoMandate.subscribe(function(val) {
    deselectOthers(val, self.ElectronicMandate, self.UploadMandate);
});

self.UploadMandate = ko.observable();
self.UploadMandate.subscribe(function(val) {
    deselectOthers(val, self.ElectronicMandate, self.NoMandate);
});

var deselectOthers = function(wasSelected) {
    if (!wasSelected) {
        // We're only interested if someone selected a checkbox.
        return;
    }
    // Loop through each of the non-wasSelected arguments.
    // - These are the observables which we wish to set to false.
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        arguments[i](false); // This is where the other observable is deselected.
    }
};
```

The `.subscribe` method is described [here](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables).